# Is there a way to send JSON to php processor without a <form>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one-page form https://apply.1hallmark.com, and I would like to collect contact information at the beginning of the form, without submitting the form. I am trying to do this with javascript.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
                    <h2 class="fs-title">Contact Information</h2>
                    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">How can we reach you?</h3>
                    <input id="firstName" type="text" name="first_name_{$Question_DivisionName}" placeholder="First Name" />
                    <input id="lastName" type="text" name="last_name_{$Question_DivisionName}" placeholder="Last Name" />
                    <input id="userEmail" type="email" name="email_address_{$Question_DivisionName}" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input id="userPhone" type="tel" name="phone_number_{$Question_DivisionName}" placeholder="Phone"/>
                    <input id="contactButton" type="button" name="go" class="action-button" value="Go!"/>
                </fieldset>
```

Javascript with some jQuery:

```
// Send Contact Info
    $(function(){
        $("#contactButton").click(function(){
            first_name = $("#firstName").val();
            last_name = $("#lastName").val();
            user_email = $("#userEmail").val();
            user_phone = $("#userPhone").val();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://apply.1hallmark.test/submit-contact.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
                "first_name": $("#firstName").val(),
                "last_name": $("#lastName").val(),
                "user_email": $("#userEmail").val(),
                "user_phone": $("#userPhone").val()
            }));
        });
    });
```

All of the submissions are currently being sent to an email address, but "POST":[], is blank. I've tried the code above. The variables are stored on button click and a post is sent to /submit-contact.php.

Comment: You can do `$.post("https://apply.1hallmark.test/submit-contact.php", { first_name, last_name, user_email, user_phone }, function (reply) { console.log(reply); });` instead of all that `xhr` business. jQuery should take care of the rest.

Comment: You can create a new `FormData` object and manually `.set(key, value)` pairs where the key and value can be anything. They don't even have to be from HTML `input` elements.

Comment: Why do you set all the variables like `first_name`, but you don't use them and repeat the calls to `.val()`?

Comment: Barmar, I originally wrote it as ```first_name``` and switched to ```.val()``` while trying to figure out why the POST was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` doesn't work with the parameters encoded as JSON. PHP will only put the parameters in `$_POST` if they're sent in `application/x-www-form-urlencode` or `multipart/form-data` format.

If you use the jQuery `$.ajax` function, or the shortcut `$.post` function, it will encode it properly.

```
$(function(){
    $("#contactButton").click(function(){
        var first_name = $("#firstName").val();
        var last_name = $("#lastName").val();
        var user_email = $("#userEmail").val();
        var user_phone = $("#userPhone").val();
        $.post("https://apply.1hallmark.test/submit-contact.php", {
            "first_name": first_name,
            "last_name": last_name,
            "user_email": user_email,
            "user_phone": user_phone
        });
    });
});
```

If you want to use `fetch()`, you can use `$.param()` to encode the POST parameter:

```
   $(function(){
        $("#contactButton").click(function(){
        var first_name = $("#firstName").val();
        var last_name = $("#lastName").val();
        var user_email = $("#userEmail").val();
        var user_phone = $("#userPhone").val();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "https://apply.1hallmark.test/submit-contact.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.send($.param({
                "first_name": first_name,
                "last_name": last_name,
                "user_email": user_email,
                "user_phone": user_phone
            }));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should work. I won't have access to the server I need to use to test this until tomorrow morning. I'll verify and be sure to mark the solution.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to send JSON to your PHP based back-end without a `<form>` element in your HTML page. This can be done with JavaScript.

Seeing that you're using JQuery, you could use the built in [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method rather than using the `XMLHttpRequest` object to simplify your code.

These changes could look like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#contactButton").click(function() {

    first_name = $("#firstName").val();
    last_name = $("#lastName").val();
    user_email = $("#userEmail").val();
    user_phone = $("#userPhone").val();

    $.ajax("https://apply.1hallmark.test/submit-contact.php",
    {
      method: 'POST',
      contents: {
        "first_name": first_name,
        "last_name": last_name,
        "user_email": user_email,
        "user_phone": user_phone
      }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log('Request response:', data)
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log('Error:', err)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>firstName</label>
<input value="test first_name" id="firstName" />
<br>
<label>lastName</label>
<input value="test last_name" id="lastName" />
<br>
<label>userEmail</label>
<input value="test user_email" id="userEmail" />
<br>
<label>userPhone</label>
<input value="test user_phone" id="userPhone" />
<br>
<button id="contactButton">ContactButton</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use the [Fetch Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to send a request to your server

example:

```
   document.getElementById('contactButton').onclick = function(){
    var url = 'yourURL.php';
    var data = {
                first_name : $("#firstName").val(),
                last_name : $("#lastName").val(),
                user_email : $("#userEmail").val(),
                user_phone : $("#userPhone").val()
    };

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response))

    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If it doesn't work with XMLHttpRequest, why do you think it will work better with Fetch?

Comment: fetch is better cause you can handle errors and you dont need to use jquery

Comment: It may be better, but does it actually solve the problem he's having? You're still using jQuery the same way he was.

Comment: @Barmar youre right I just copy his click event thats why I added the vanilla js statement =)